# How to extract html table into XML file?

Tags: asp.net

I have a HTML table stored in a string

```
string tbl  = "<table calls='report'><tr><th>head</th><th>name</th></tr><tr><td>Department name</td><td>Mike</th></tr></table>";
```

how can i loop thru this string and then write it to an XML file?

I think i will be able to write the file to XML but the question is how or loop thru the string and identify whats in t and how to parse it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since HTML is already XML, you could leave it as it is and meet your objective.  But I assume you want semantically meaningful tag names.

You might try the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  This allows you to write queries against an object model, similar to the way you can do it with XDocument and Linq-to-XML.  I quote:

> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports
>   plain XPATH or XSLT (you     actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH
>   nor XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that
>   allows you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very
>   tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very
>   similar to what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or
>   streams).

It also supports Linq, if you aren't familiar with XPATH et al.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ann. The reason i want to do that is because i want to create an exportable excel file. so when you click on a button a function parse the HTML string and then place it in Excel file! I don't know how to install the Agility Pack

Comment: If I remember correctly, it uses NuGet to install the Agility Pack directly into your VS project. Are you familiar with NuGet? I am not at my programming machine right now but I believe your first step would be to install the NuGet VS Extension. Then reboot. You can then use NuGet's interface to search for and download and install the Agility Pack.